# how to replace all occurrence of string between two symbols?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, special-characters

I'm working with RegEx on Javascript and here is where I stuck.

I have a simple string like

```
<html><body><span style=3D"font-family:Verdana; color:#000; font-size:10pt;=
"><div><font face=3D"verdana, geneva" size=3D"2">http://72.55.146.142:8880/=
order003.png.zip,120</body></html>
```

all i need to do is write javascript which can replace all strings in with  "<" and ">" symbol.

I wrote something like this -

```
var strReplaceAll = Body;
var intIndexOfMatch = strReplaceAll.indexOf( "<" );

while (intIndexOfMatch != -1){

    strReplaceAll = strReplaceAll.replace(/<.*>/,'')

    intIndexOfMatch = strReplaceAll.indexOf( "<" );
}
```

but the problem is if body contains -

```
test<abc>test2<adg>
```

it will give me -

```
test
```

only or if body contains like -

```
<html>test<abc>test2<adg>
```

it will give me nothing please let me know how i can get-

```
testtest2
```

as a final output.

Comment: [`Java` != `JavaScript`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245069/1393766). Anyway you probably should read about greedy and reluctant quantifiers.

Comment: is that the simple string contain newline characters?

Comment: What's the `3D` doing before opening quotes?

Comment: Using jQuery, you can easily get it with `$('outer-most-tag-name').text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
<[^>]+>
```

**DEMO:**

http://regex101.com/r/kI5cJ7/2

**DISCUSSION**

Put the html code in a string and apply to this string the regex.

```
var htmlCode = ...;
htmlCode = htmlCode.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

The original regex take too much characters (`*` is a greedy operator).

Check this page about [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), especially the part on *"Watch Out for The Greediness!"*.

> Most people new to regular expressions will attempt to use `<.+>`. They will be surprised when they test it on a string like `This is a <EM>first</EM> test`. You might expect the regex to match `<EM>` and when continuing after that match, `</EM>`.
>
> But it does not. The regex will match `<EM>first</EM>`. Obviously not what we wanted.

Comment: While this works, it's a hack based on the lack of `">"` in the HTML tags. Parsing HTML means you'll never get it right - see `<a def="joy>cat>12">`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(<.*?>)/
```

Just use this. Replace all the occurrences with `""`.

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/lK9zP6/1)