# Replace a multiple times a substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, substring

I need to replace everything between `:` and `,` with a `|` multiple times.
I have a server list like `server1:127.0.0.1,server2:127.0.0.2,server3:127.0.0.3`.

Basically, I need to remove all the IPs and replace them with some `|`.

So far I was able to do this:

```
resultList = serverList.replace(/:.*,/g, '|')
```

The problem is that the result list is `server1|server3:127.0.0.3`.

How can I replace every occurrence?

Comment: greedy matching ruins your regex. Use `[^,]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace all occurrence of string between two symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606731/how-to-replace-all-occurrence-of-string-between-two-symbols)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/:.*,/` is greedily matching `:127.0.0.1,server2:127.0.0.2`.  Remember that quantifiers like `*` will match *as much as they can* while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

Consider specifying `[^,]` instead of `.`.  This will exclude commas from matching and therefore limit the match to just the region you want to remove.

```
resultList = serverList.replace(/:[^,]*,/g, '|')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a lazy approach with `?` (Matches as few characters as possible).

```js
var string = 'server1:127.0.0.1,server2:127.0.0.2,server3:127.0.0.3';

console.log(string.replace(/:.*?(,|$)/g, '|'));
```