# replacing a characters within a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a string in which there are words like this `<00asjdask>`
for example

```
 var str="hello <00dansld> this is ur system <00aldjs> and you are <00jdak>"
```

So I have to make the words inside brackets `<>` in bold and print it inside an html page so in html page it would look like

```
hello < <b>00dansld<b> > this is ur system < <b> 00aldjs <b> > .
```

how can I do it ? I thought of using regex but I don't know how ?

Comment: Are string in <> fixed ?

Comment: [Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Can you share what you've tried?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). I've attempted to translate your code as best I can, it would of been much better if you'd done this yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace all occurrence of string between two symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606731/how-to-replace-all-occurrence-of-string-between-two-symbols)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Regex `<(\w+)>` and replace every occurence with `&lt;<strong>$1</strong>&gt;`:

```js
const text = "hello <00dansld> this is ur system <00aldjs>";

const replaced = text.replace(/<(\w+)>/g,'&lt;<strong>$1</strong>&gt;');

document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
```

Comment: what if i want to keep the brackets also <> and inside of that bold characters .

Comment: @saurabhkapoor I edited my answer to match your comment.

Comment: Thanks for solution